# Default gender, "Male" or "Female"

Tags: dropdown, gender

Should our default gender when selecting male/female on the dropdown list be based on the local [sex ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_ratio) (if a country have more female than male then female is the default value)?

Comment: It depends. What are you creating? How and where are you marketing it? The number of men or women in a country is not what makes the difference. For example, a website about makeup will probably have more female visitors than male, even if it's a city of mostly men. Also, it might be worth considering whether you need gender. Article about this: http://www.sarahmei.com/blog/2010/11/26/disalienation

Comment: So if someone forgets to enter their gender, you plan on recording it as whatever the default is?

Comment: FYI you're asking for sex not gender, at least presumably gender is less relevant. Besides, sex ratio is usually almost exactly a 50% split with about 2% margin of error--I would never assume a default based on numbers, even ignoring the reasons others have stated below

Comment: Even sex isn't a simple Male/Female - at least allow a blank option for the few who don't fall into either

Comment: @BenBrocka there are a number of countries with large skew's in the ratio due to selective abortions.

Comment: IMHO, I'd first ask if this is even information that is really important to collect.

Comment: I will add two more options, "Unknown" and "Indeterminate"

Comment: Or you could just add one more option of "I'd rather not share".

Comment: Why do you need the gender? Is there a real, true, legitimate need for it? How about just leaving it out entirely?

Comment: I always want to select "Alpha-Male", but those radio-buttons never let me...

@Ben Brocka: Don't assume a 50/50 ratio on each site. Depending on the topic you could get more than 90% of the one or other gender (tech/gadgets/cars vs. diet/cooking etc.)

Comment: Choose whatever produces the least number of clicks for the majority that are filling in the form.  If the site is directed for women then women.  Same for men.  If it is a 50/50 split, then provide a 'please fill in' option instead to not put anyone's nose out of joint.

Comment: Building on what @JuliusA said, check out the ISO standard for the representation of human sexes: Not known, Male, Female and Not applicable.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_5218

Comment: Every time I come across a form with male / female / rather not say, it annoys me. It should be male / female / other / rather not say, at a minimum. I am happy to disclose my gender, if the form actually gives me an option to do so accurately.

Comment: Add another "why are you asking?" question. If you have a real need to know, then that need will *significantly* influence any answer I might give.  In particular, if you actually need to know, then you need to consider that gender is a lot more complex than the answers on offer here suggest.

If you *don't* have have a real need to know, then don't ask.

If you have to ask, have a look at this similar question:
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19923/should-gender-be-required-or-is-there-a-better-way-to-collect-this-informatio?rq=1

Comment: @Darren you seem to be neglecting the cost of an error, which can be much more than a single click, and the probability of which is increased by your suggestion.  A plausible scenario is it's 60/40 women/men.  By your logic, the form should have "woman" checked, so that only 40% of people need to click to switch it. The problem is, each time a man mistakenly neglects to switch it, it's now wrong and the recipe for fixing it is likely *far* more complicated than a single click, if it can even be found or even exists at all.  For this reason, perhaps it's better to not have a default.

Comment: That said, it's sad if a site is directed for women more than men or vice versa.  I'd much rather not ask at all, and not be asked, as a user.

Comment: default: none. Users may want to avoid sharing this information anyway, so make the default and empty option.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**You don't select a default at all**

Using a drop down list or a radio group - you let the user decide - and this also prevents accidental submission of a form without the user setting this value (assuming it's gets validated) because there is no other way of validating it - only the user knows their gender so there is no right/wrong validation other than 'is it set'

Here are examples from Windows Live ID sign-up, Facebook sign-up, Yahoo sign-up

[image]

[image]

[image]

In fact in my own survey of over 100 high profile sign-up forms:

Only 20% of those sites asked the gender of which:

- 20 did not pre-select - by using one of the options above.
- 2 forms prefilled with the option 'Female' ([bebo](http://www.bebo.com/c/invite/join) and [foursquare](https://foursquare.com/signup/join))
- 0 forms prefilled with 'Male'

Furthermore - of the 20 that did not pre-select:

- 2 sites - [TypePad](https://www.typepad.com/secure/services/register?acct_level=pro) and [Etsy](https://www.etsy.com/join?from_page=http://www.etsy.com/&ref=so_reg), gave options to not provide gender via a third option:

[image]

[Grooveshark](http://grooveshark.com/#/signup) go the extra mile (although I'd at least expect consistency)

- to try and make it clearer by using symbols on their sign up:

[image]

- or in their 'edit profile' they use another version in which the wording has clearly been carefully considered and accounts for the gender/sex issue as to how the user identifies themselves:

[image]

Comment: Got an external article you can link to where you provide more info about it all?

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Sorry, *wish* I could say yes but no not at the moment - not enough hours in the day!

Comment: Check out the wording on the Grooveshark one. Remember that some people do find it difficult to answer these questions. Maybe you could edit your answer to include this example? http://imgur.com/odxmx

Comment: +1 Good answer, my thoughts exactly. Would be interesting to do some empirical testing to find out how many people would "forget" to change the gender (i.e. how many males are registered as female for bebo and foursquare).

Comment: @billynomates1 - thanks! I have added grooveshark - but using the current iconified version

Comment: Not sure that Grooveshark's symbols actually make anything *clearer*. (What if I want to log in as male but I'm not wearing a baseball cap???)

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "rather not say" option. This is a pretty sensitive subject. When Google+ launched, having a published sex was mandatory. This caused an enormous stir. Randall Munroe wrote [a comprehensive post](https://plus.google.com/111588569124648292310/posts/SeBqgN9Zoiu) on the subject.

Comment: @RogerAttrill - The one I got a screenshot of was from the "Edit Profile" section. I'm surprised they differ, really! But my point was the wording of "I identify as" includes people who's legal sex differs from their gender.

Comment: @billynomates1 - ok I didn't realise there were going to be two different versions depending on the form!! Ive added that one as well because it does address some sensitive isues. Thank you.

Comment: TypePad and Etsy have the right idea: no default, and offer an option to rather not say. Depending on the audience, you may want to offer more choices.

Comment: "Rather not say" is a step in the right direction, but it still excludes "I'd like to say, but I'm neither!"

Answer (score 18):

How about asking the user to select their gender in the form of their preferred third-person pronoun ("his", "her", "their"), instead of providing their biological sex?

Listing "their" rather than "its", because I doubt anyone wants to be referred to as "it".  For example:

```
Which sentence sounds right?
[ ] <user> updated his profile.
[ ] <user> updated her profile.
[ ] <user> updated their profile.
```

Comment: +1. This looks rather odd at first, but "Which pronouns do you prefer?" is actually the **standard** way to ask questions about gender in spaces which are friendly to trans and genderqueer people.

Comment: I feel this comes with the extra price of confusing every or almost every user. You have to stop and think what's being asked.

Comment: this only works in some languages like English. You can't use this in some other languages

Comment: Similar to this, I've seen in a lot of sites where you choose how you prefer to be called: Mr/Mrs/Ms. Which can be adapted to other languages than english.

Comment: @Luciano, not really. I don't think many languages differentiate between Mrs and Ms.

Comment: @RuudLenders Portuguese does: Sra / Srta. Similar for Italian / Spanish, so possibly other languages as well. You don't need many more languages than those to cover good part of the world. But that's beside the point.

Comment: Forgot to mention the neutral pronouns, besides They/Them, some people prefer Ey/Em, Ze/Hir, Ze/Zir, Ze/Zem, etc.

Comment: The question is about what the default should be, not what the options should be. Although there are questions covering just that!

Answer (score 7):

Unless you have a good reason to have the gender, I would agree with @Roger that not pre-selecting is the best option. I would also add that not validating at all, and allowing a selection of Male and Female is probably the best option.

The clientelle of the site is also important, and not always obvious. Females are far more common users of web sites - especially e-commerce - than are normally expected. Knowing your users is critical if you insist on setting a default - many of the sites I have worked on, female would be default.

Answer (score 4):

In form fields like that, I usually make the **first value null**, to indicate no item was selected.

As far as order, I would either defer to the audience, then just go standard
M/F

For the drop down, make it optional, with the default value of null (so as to allow form submission without error)

```
Gender:
Select one  <null>
Male        <male>
Female      <female>
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you should not leave a default option if you want to get this information. Just use radio buttons, for example. And validate that the user has selected an option on submit.

Comment: Radio buttons should have a default selection. Point 9 http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

Comment: @rk Yes. This comment should be on most answers on this question, from the look of it.