# Which of these two form layouts is better (more "material")

Tags: forms, android, material-design

Consider the two form layouts shown below[image]

The context here is an Android app targeting Android v 4.4+. The controls are

1. A select box which I have attempted to make flat
2. A readonly input which when tapped shows a popup dialog with a circuar selector
3. A username

What looks "wrong" to me

- Without at least the bottom border the selectbox on the l.h.s. does not look/feel like a select box
- I feel the Age label + input on the l.h.s. does not scale well to large screens

I hope that someone with more UX experience than I can provide a few insights here.

Comment: Why is there so much white space at the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your observations are correct! Do check some standard interaction patterns  of [select-box](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/select-field) and [text-field](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field)

Based on your current layout, I will suggest you choose one of these:

[image]

---

## OR

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  What is the current view on using floating labels - i.e. labels that occupy the same space as their companion form control and "float up" to indicate the function of that control when required as discussed [here](https://css-tricks.com/float-labels-css/)

Comment: @DroidOS That one is definitely intuitive.. the animation makes  interaction even better compared to the still labels/placeholders.

Answer (score 5):

If the `Age` input is opening a dropdown or picker of some kind, I suggest you use the dropdown arrow. Otherwise it will look like a text input where the user is supposed to enter text.

In the gender select box I would not include the "I'd rather not disclose my gender", because if a user selected a gender then he will have no hint that in the options of the select box there is this option.

[image]

Thanks @AdrianMaire for the comment on the [gender default](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/).

Comment: Good point on the *I'd not rather disclose my gender* :)

Comment: As user, I feel not secure the gender is not disclosed, because it is still there selected in the select-box. Personally I rather prefer the 3-state select-box.

Comment: @AdrianMaire the current image displays a selected state. But the default could be ["Select a gender"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/default-gender-male-or-female). I'll edit that, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Alvaro - I'd rather not disclose my gender is actually the default choice.  However, you make a valid point - once the user has selected a gender they may not realize that this option exists