# Using required sign for inputs with default value

Tags: guidelines, required-fields

Should we use a required sign (*) for the inputs which cannot be left empty since they always contain some default value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure.

#### But be careful!

As a general practice, I tend to avoid defaulting fields that do not have an appropriate default. Instead, use a `Please Select...` option (or similar) that acts as an empty placeholder.

For example, the `Gender` field in your example doesn't have an appropriate default—[there is no "default gender"](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/default-gender-male-or-female/13420#13420). Additionally, if someone just "skips" the field, they'll now have submitted their form with inaccurate data which they didn't provide themselves.

<sup>Side note: be careful talking about collecting gender in forms around here... you'll get an earful really quick.</sup>

On the other hand, fields like `Notification frequency` or `App background color` could very well be safely defaulted.

**Regardless of if the required field has an empty state, add the required indicator**.

1. It logically fits the idea of what the indicator represents: data that must be submitted with the form is marked as required, regardless of if the user can erase it.
2. It will minimize the likeliness of a user failing to submit a form properly due to a missing field.
3. It is a non-obtrusive way to communicate a valuable attribute of the form field.
4. It is a common convention. Modern web forms as well as government documents use this symbol (or similar) for denoting required fields.

I can't really think of a strong argument against it. Just implement it so it's not distracting and fits into the aesthetics of your site/app.

Comment: The question is - should it be used for the fields which CANNOT BE EMPTY? As in example above, the field 'Gender' cannot be missed since it always has some option selected.

Comment: @RomanPavlyk I see. I initially understood "cannot be empty" to mean "is required". Edited.